# Dominated series

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $\alpha_n$ is such that  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n$ is absolutely convergent. Show that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha_n x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}$$
is a dominated series on $\mathbb{R}$.

Dominated series definition:

We say that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n$ is a dominated
series if there exists a sequence $a_n$ of positive real numbers such that

$$|f_n(x)| \leqslant a_n, \quad \forall x \in \color{red}{J}, \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $$

and the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges.

Can someone help me prove this?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What have you tried? It should be a very simple exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly we have that
$$
\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}} < 1,
$$
because denominator is greater than numerator ($2n$ ensure that $x^{2n}$ is positive).

So we have
$$
\frac{|a_n|x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}} < |a_n|.
$$
Since $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is absolutely converent, we know that no $|a_n|$ is infinite.

Overall, this implies that we found the domination series which is in our case $|a_n|$ (absolute value is of course positive).
Hence $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_nx^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}$ is dominated in $\mathbb{R}$ by $|a_n|$.